# How to create a pipe in c under Windows

Tags: c, windows, pipe

I am trying to create a pipe in my c program to input data to another program myProgram.exe. All I need to do is to get myProgram running and send "quit" from the main program. The problem is I don't know how I can create a pipe in c.

I got a working Perl example somewhere:

```
open(myHandle, ".../myProgram.exe");
//... (do something else) ...
printf(myHandle, "quit");
close(myHandle);
```

Can somebody please help me translate this into c code? Please keep in mind I'm running under Windows so there is no unistd.h available.

Cheers, B

Comment: See CreateNamedPipe function. However, for simple message like this it is better to use named event.

Comment: Can't you use another mechanism?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. If I call CreateNamedPipe, how do I specify in which program I want to pipe? Could you please post a code sample? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've recently posted a simple example how to create pipes for inter-process communication:

See [Create Named Pipe C++ Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561604/create-named-pipe-c-windows/26561999#26561999)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have a simple question: to connect a client to the pipe, do I have to necessarily edit the code in the client program (add the line with CreateFile etc.)? I want to feed my client some input, but in my case I have the client program from somewhere else and I really don't want to change anything in the code there. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Yes you have to do that. If you don't want to change the other application you can create the application with a new handle to STDOUT/STDIN. Check the documentation of attribute of `STARTUPINFO` structure and function `CreateProcess(..)`.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I set the new handlesto STDOUT/STDIN as you suggested. I transmuted this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I didn't make any changes in my client program. I managed to get it running and pipe no more than a single command to it. It is not optimal, but for my needs it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780(v=vs.85).aspx

There is a lot of information about pipes under windows there.

Also see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365781(v=vs.85).aspx

For a list of pipe-related functions in WINAPI