# Is there a way for an Windows service to communicate with an Electron App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, service, electron

I have a Windows Service polling periodically whether my app in running or not. When it is, the service checks for an update on a server. If there is an update, I need a way for the service to let the app know it is available so the user can be notified.

Is this possible?

Comment: Write it to a file, and have the app set up a "file created" notify on that file.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to do this in a [tag:windows-service] (if so, retag to that) instead of straight in javascript? Node.JS can easily poll URLs for updates.

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the IPC means, by creating a named pipe (socket)

```
 //"PIPE_NAME" :"the_name_of_the_pipe",
 //"PIPE_PATH" : "\\\\.\\pipe\\"
 const net = require('net');
 let socketClient = net.createConnection(config.get('PIPE_PATH') + config.get('PIPE_NAME'), () => {
    console.log('connected to service!');
});
socketClient.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
socketClient.on('error', (error) => {
    //console.log(`Couldn't connect to service : ${error.toString()}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
        socketClient.connect(config.get('PIPE_PATH') + config.get('PIPE_NAME'), () => {
            console.log('connected to service!');
        });
    }, 4000);
});
socketClient.on('end', () => {
    console.log('disconnected from service');
    socketClient.connect(config.get('PIPE_PATH') + config.get('PIPE_NAME'), () => {
        console.log('connected to service!');
    });
});
```

I used `Qt` for the service side and created `QLocalServer` to exchange messages between the service and electron app but you can use and find many examples out there

you can create a namedpipe that listens

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561999/3339316
HANDLE hPipe;
char buffer[1024];
DWORD dwRead;


hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"),
                        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,   // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
                        1,
                        1024 * 16,
                        1024 * 16,
                        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                        NULL);
while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
    {
        while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
        {
            /* add terminating zero */
            buffer[dwRead] = '\0';

            /* do something with data in buffer */
            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
    }

    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
}
```