How to run two executables and communicate with them separately in C++?
I am coding a chess engine in C++. This engine uses the universal chess interface (UCI). This means I can communicate with it via the console. I type some command in the console and it responds in the console.
But for further improvement of my engine I need to be able to test it. I want to do that by letting my engine play against older versions of itself. So I want to write a C++ program which runs two engines separately by running two executables. And I need to be able to communicate with them on separate "channels". This just means I need to able to send commands to one engine at the time.
Is that even possible and if so how would I do that?
I am using Windows 11 with a x86-64 architecture.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output

Basically, this sounds as if you need to launch two more processes (one per "engine"), and connect their stdin/stdout to pipes on your side. for Windows, my starting point would like be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output followed by a detour to boost (because I use boost a lot) to figure out how to get Windows handles wrapped into streams.

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561604/create-windows-named-pipe-in-c

The Boost.Process library should let you do this in a more portable and simpler way.

Being C++ would it not be simpler to make your "engine" a class and simply create two instances to play each other?  That would not preclude also supporting UCI.

I'm afraid you will have to expand your application to use Interprocess communications. There are several ways to do that in win32. I recommend using pipes, there are examples.
